# Google structured data testing tool not seeing content loaded dynamically in a Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have an SPA (Backbone.js) which uses a 3rd party JS library to dynamically load some content onto the page. This content has structured data markup but [Google's tool for structured data](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) is not finding it.

This library waits until Backbone places a div on the page and when it sees the div it loads the content. I think what is happening is google is scanning the page before that div can be loaded from the item record on the template.

Can anything be done to make Backbone load that div earlier, in order for the content to be seen by Google?

Comment: does the tool run javascript?

Comment: GSDTT does not process inject JSON-LD; it has to be inline.